# (matlab) write csv file from cell data

Tags: matlab, csv

I created the cell file in matlab.

[This is the cell the name is "Table". In this Table,{1,1} is name of city, {1,2}&{1,3} are longitude and latitude values.
{1,4},{1,6},{1,8},{1,10} has the name(characters), and {1,5},{1,7},{1,9},{1,11} has the number with the range which is shown in the picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTjDr.png)

I would like to create the csv file from this Table. 
At first i tried the "csvwrite" function but it is not working in that situation.

In addition, I also create files depending on the columns.

```
for i=1:25
 County_value(i,1) = Table{1,1+(i-1)*11};
 County_lon(i,1) = Table{1,2+(i-1)*11};
 County_lat(i,1) = Table{1,3+(i-1)*11};

 D_apt(:,1+2*(i-1)) = Table{1,4+(i-1)*11};
 D_apt{:,2*i} = num2cell(Table{1,5+(i-1)*11})

end
```

---

I succeeded County Value,lon,lat and D_apt(:,1+2*(i-1)). However, there is error when i try to create D_apt{:,2*i}...

I need your help!!

Thank you and Thank you a lot of your help!!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [mathworks docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvwrite.html)

> csvwrite(filename,M) writes matrix M into filename as comma-separated values. The filename input is a character vector specified as text enclosed in single quotes, for example, 'csvlist.dat'.

Thus your call to csvwrite fails because it can only handle matrices, not cells. Furthermore, your code has several issues:

1. You don't specify the size of the `County_value`, `County_lon` and `Count_lat` vectors. More importantly, `County_value` seems to store strings that can have different lengths and the assingmente `County_value(i,1) = Table{1+(-1)*11}` can induce errors.
2. You don't initialize the `D_apt` cell. In particular, your sintax `D_apt(:,1+2*(i-1)) = Table{1,4+(i-1)*11};` tries to resize the `D_apt` variable to a 2 dimensional cell whose values are given in the `Table` elements.
3. It is unclear how you wish to write the data to a csv file.

In order to write the csv file using the cell you supply you have two choices:

1. Use an fprintf statement with a format string that suites your needs.
2. Tinker with the cell to get matrices that can be handled correctly by csvwrite.

I would go for the first option to solve your particular issue, but keep in mind that if you are able to change the code that created the cell, if may be cleaner or simpler to split the cell into separate variables for the numeric and string values.

```
csvfile = fopen('csvfilename.csv','w');
delimiter = ',';
if isunix
    newline = '\n';
else
    newline = '\r\n';
end
for i = 1:length(Table)
    index11 = mod(i-1/11)+1;
    if index11==1 % City
        fprintf(csvfile,['%s',delimiter],Table{i});
    elseif index11==2 || index==3 % Lon or Lat
        fprintf(csvfile,['%f',delimiter],Table{i});
    elseif mod(index11,2)==0 % Pair indeces: Names
        fprintf(csvfile,['%s',delimiter],Table{i});
    else % Impair indeces: Values
        if index11<11
            fprintf(csvfile,['%s',delimiter],mat2str(Table{i}));
        else
            fprintf(csvfile,['%s',newline],mat2str(Table{i}));
        end
    end
end
```

I am sorry if I did not manage to understand what you meant with

> {1,5},{1,7},{1,9},{1,11} has the number with the range which is shown in the picture.

but the image was not really legible.